# Difference between GitLab CI and GitHub Actions Beta

Tags: gitlab, github-actions

What is the difference between [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) and [GitHub Actions Beta](https://help.github.com/en/categories/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions)?
Both talk about devops/automation from Git repo

Comment: I think it's just a different CI...

Answer (score 10):

[GitHub copied a lot of Gitlab`s features](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/05/23/gitlab-features-compared-github/), including CI (similar configuration and price). Actions looks like GitLab CI/CD but there are some differences between them.

GitLab CI/CD has integration with Pages, issues, packages registry, it has environments dashboard, review support, manual pipelines, multi-project pipelines, support a lot of different reports (such as Container scanning report), good API, ability to use your own runner, and a lot of other features. Also, it is open source.

You can see more full comparsion [here](https://about.gitlab.com/devops-tools/github-vs-gitlab.html#comparison)

GitHub Actions - simple CI; GitLab CI/CD - configurable and powerful open-source CI/CD with integrations with different software and unique features.

Answer (score 5):

As the commenter said above, it's basically just each company's answer to CI/CD. There are minor differences but the basic premise is the same.

You can see a side-by-side comparison from a third party at https://knapsackpro.com/ci_comparisons/github-actions/vs/gitlab-ci.